# Can I ask for tips for administering a server that hosts user-generated CC-BY-NC-SA content?

Tags: copyright

I'm hosting a wiki where users agree to publish their contributions under CC-BY-**NC**-SA.

Since it's a lot of work to administer the server, I've thought about letting people **tip** me for my work, meaning net earnings.

This would be separate from a potential **donations** link to cover hosting costs, where I would limit the amount taken so as to keep the balance at zero.

Does the fact that users offer their contributions under an NC license mean that I would be breaking the license terms if I asked for tips somewhere on the website?

To be honest, this question is more out of curiosity than anything, because ultimately the decision will be based on community feedback.  If I put a link to a tipping pledge onto the homepage, highly active contributors would be justified to ask: "Why not a link to a tipping pledge for **me** who adds so much content to the wiki?" That's a social topic more than a legal topic though.

Comment: Did you read the definition of NonCommercial in the license itself? https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/legalcode